# How do I read/write files to an unknown user directory?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, directory

I'm attempting to read and write files from a User Directory, (C:\Users\USERNAME\Test Source) But I've been unsuccessful in finding any resources on how I can auto detect the name of the user, USERNAME in the above example, or anyway that I can have it read and write to the directory without knowledge off what a users name is.
Could anyone point me towards the right direction or methods for this, if it's even a logical request?  I'm not sure how much difference, if any, it makes but this program is being written in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in windows command line

```
 echo %username%
```

or

```
  whoami
```

for getting the username of the user who is currently logged in .
Store it in a variable and then append it to the path name.

You can also use

```
‘C:\users\%username%\file‘
```

directly .To check through `whoami` do

```
l=`whoami`
echo $l
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'll try that out. I've been trying to figure this out for weeks now.... I'm very new to actually programming.

Comment: After attempting this for 20 minutes I just now realized you said, "Store it in a variable and then append it to the path name." Finally got this to work. Thank you.

Comment: Good to know it worked for you . You need to accept the answer as correct (by clicking on the checkmark below the answer) if it works.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is this:

```
import os
print os.path.expanduser('~')
```

Append your folder to the path like so:

```
userdir = os.path.expanduser('~')
print os.path.join(userdir, 'Test Source')
```

Besides requiring the least lines of code, this method has the advantage of working under every OS (Linux, Windows XP / 7 / 8 / etc).

Comment: Also a good example of using `os.path.join()` instead of combining the strings yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `%userprofile%` variable in your path if you're on Windows:

```
%userprofile%\Test Source\file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. Very new to programming here.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> import getpass
>>> import os.path

>>> usename = getpass.getuser()
>>> mypath = os.path.join("C:\Users", username, "Test Source")
```