# Java How to read/write files to/from any user's desktop

Tags: java, file, io, desktop

I want to read a file from the user's desktop, and then write a new file to the desktop. Below is the code to do this on my own computer, but I'm not sure how to do it for any user.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357554/how-do-i-read-write-files-to-an-unknown-user-directory) previously-asked question, but I'm not sure how to implement such a method in Java. Would I possibly use the [`System.getProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) method?

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thanks!

```
public static String [] read()
{
    ArrayList<String> fileArrList = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("File name > ");
    String fileName = scan.nextLine();

    try
    {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\pez\\Desktop\\" + fileName));

        while (file.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = file.nextLine();
            fileArrList.add(line);
        }

        file.close();

        String [] fileArr = new String[fileArrList.size()];
        fileArr = fileArrList.toArray(fileArr);

        return fileArr;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }

    return null;
}

public static void writeNewFile(ArrayList outputArr)
{
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\pez\\Desktop\\output.txt", false);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);

        for (Object i : outputArr)
        {
            pw.println(i);
        }

        pw.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
    {
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the system property `user.home`:

```
    File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "/Desktop"); 
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(desktop, fileName));
```

I assume you know you are limited to windows environments this way.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to maintain usability across all platforms, without specifically asking the user to input the location of the file?

Comment: `user.home` is platform-independent, but the location of the desktop directory varies between different desktop environments in linux

Comment: Thanks, that worked. How can I modify the `writeNewFile()` function to automatically write to the desktop and name the file `output.txt`? I've tried several things and the code compiles and runs, but the file never shows up on the desktop.

Comment: Make sure to create the file with `File output = new File(desktop, "output.txt")` and `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(output)`. Maybe  debug and inspect the resulting path of `output`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you simple examples that you can implement in your project.
To get windows username you can get the property `user.name`:

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

To write on a file you can use this simple code:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("filename.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println("Some text");
writer.println("Some other text");
writer.close();
```

To read a text file you can use this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/filename.txt"));
String textLine = null;
while ((textLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(textLine);
}
```

You can implement all this code in your project easily.
I hope you find this usefull, sorry for my english.